# Which subsets out of S, W and T form subspace of the vector space V?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

$V = \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$ 
$S = \{f : f$ is monotone$\}$ 
$T = \{f : f(2) = (f(5))^5\}$ 
$W = \{f : f(2) = f(5)\}$

Note that monotone means either non-decreasing or non-increasing.

***My Attempt:***

**For S**:

> It's not a subspace of V and it can be shown with a counterexample which violates the fact that vector spaces are closed under some binary operation (addition in this case).
> $
> f_1(x) = x\\
> f_2(x) = -2x \\
> f_3(x) = f_1(x) + f_2(x)\\
> $

> $ f_3(x)= 
>   \begin{cases}
>     (-x) + (-2(-x)) = x,& \text{if } x \in (-\infty, 0) \\
>     x + (-2x) = -x ,& \text{if } x \in (-\infty, 0)\\
>  \end{cases}
> $

> $f_3(x)$ is not monotonic, hence S is not a subset of V. [**Reason**: S is not closed under addition.]

**For W**:

> For a non-decreasing monotonic function, $f$, if $x \leq y$, then $f(x) \leq f(y).$ 
> We know that 
> $$2 \leq 5 \\
> f(2) \leq f(5) \\$$
> But it is given that
> $$f(2) = f(5)$$
> Hence, $f$ must be a constant function and it can be defined as $$f(x) = k, \text{ such that } k \in \mathbb{R}$$
> It can be shown that a family fo constant funstions contains a function which is zero everywhere and it is closed under addition and scalar multiplication. Hence, W is a subspace of V.

Comment: Please show your attempt. If you have not started yet I suggest you start with $W$.

Comment: For $S$, it may help to consider low-degree polynomials. For $T$, already constant functions should give you insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

W is the only one which is subspace of $R^R$ cause....
W forms a vector space in itself.

In T the scalar multiplication doesn't hold.

In S we can find a non-decreasing function $f$ and a non- increasing function $g$ and create a fault in the addition so that $f+g $ doesn't stay monotone.

Comment: It was quite confused with T, specifically. Thank you so the help.